Users can concurrently withdraw above their wallet balance by initiating multiple concurrent withdrawals
I am updating a finance application built on node.js, mongodb and ```mongoose`` and I am currently facing a challenge with the logic to process fund withdrawals from the system. The problem is that a user can request an amount greater than their balance if they hit the fund withdrawal endpoint concurrently. For instance, with an available balance of $10, the user can process multiple $10 withdrawals as long as they do it concurrently.
I know where the problem is coming from, just that I have been unable to resolve it. I know this is happening because the actions are taking place concurrently so the user.balance will always be 10 because the debit happens after the read. I am relatively new to backend development so pardon me if I don't use the correct terminologies. This is what my code looks like.
 try{
   // Perform tasks such as validating the account number, etc.

   const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

   if(user.balance < req.body.amount)
     return res.status(400).send({message:"Insufficient Balance"});

    // update the user balance in the DB to user.balance - req.body.amount

    return res.status(200).send({message:"Fund has been sent to the account provided"})
 }

I tried an approach of updating the user record in the collection and using that response to check the user balance but I am not so sure if this will fix my issue completely or if there will still be loopholes or if there is a better way to handle this.
This is the second approach I tried out
 try{

   // Perform tasks such as validating the account number, etc.
   const idx = uuid()

   const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {withdrawal_intent:idx} {
        new: true,
   });


   if(user.balance < req.body.amount)
     return res.status(400).send({message:"Insufficient Balance"});

    // update the user balance in the DB to user.balance - req.body.amount

    return res.status(200).send({message:"Fund has been sent to the account provided"})
 }

I am open to remodelling the code to fit the best possible way to handle this
P.S: It's an old codebase so I might be using an old syntax of mongoose.
"mongoose": "^5.9.9"

Short answer:
Race condition the concern in this question can be handled using the method findOneAndUpdate. The most important point is the conditional passed into this method. This should always check that the update being performed should not lead to a negative value. A sample code is given below, while reading it, please take advantage of the comments incorporated in it.
Detailed answer:
Please read through this post sequentially.
Conditional update:
Conditional update is a common optimistic approach to keep data consistent in the face of concurrent accessing, that is, consistency in the face of concurrency.
It works on the principle that any client that does an update tests the value just before updating to see if it has changed since the last read. If the test fails, then a race condition - write-write conflict, has occurred, and the current update should be aborted informing users about the situation. For this original question, the test for race condition has been implemented as the updating would not lead to a negative balance.
The following code would demonstrate it. It is mainly based on the method findOneAndUpdate as it would perform three operations - find, update and read, in an atomic way. For further details, please see the comments given in the code. Two of the statements in the code require some additional information as below.
The statement - statement #1 : This is the statement causing a race condition in the code. At present it is uncommented. In order to run the code without creating a race condition, please comment this statement.
The statement - statement #2 : This is the statement wherein the conditional update has been implemented, the condition -  { a: 'A', b: { $gte: orgdoc.b } }, is doing the job.
// MongoDB: 7.0.2
// Mongoose : 8.3.2
// Node.js v21.6.0.
//conditionalUpdate.mjs

import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');

  const someSchema = new Schema({ a: String, b: Number });
  const SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema);
  await SomeModel.deleteMany();

  // creating original document.
  const orgdoc = await SomeModel({
    a: 'A',
    b: 1,
  }).save();

  // deducting value
  const latestvalue = orgdoc.b - 1;

  // let us assume this operation is being executed by a separate client program in another session
  // performing a concurrent update against the same document
  // statement #1
  await SomeModel.updateOne({ a: 'A' }, { $inc: { b: -1 } });

  // performing a conditional update to safeguard
  // the possible write-write conflict
  // statement #2
  const updateQuery = SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { a: 'A', b: { $gte: orgdoc.b } },
    { b: latestvalue },
    { new: true }
  );
  const newdoc = await updateQuery.exec();

  // informing user for the needful action
  if (newdoc) {
    console.log(`Updation passed`);
  } else {
    console.log(
      `Updation failed - write-write conflict detected, please check the latest document against yours`
    );
  }
  console.log(`Original document: ${orgdoc}`);
  console.log(`Update Query: ${updateQuery}`);
  console.log(`Latest document : ${await SomeModel.findOne({ a: 'A' })}`);
}

// Output 1: When statement #1 is uncommented
// Updation failed - write-write conflict detected, please check the latest document against yours
// Original document: { a: 'A', b: 1, _id: ..., __v: 0 }
// Update Query: SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate({ a: 'A', b: { '$gte': 1 } }, { '$set': { b: 0 } })
// Latest document : { _id: ..., a: 'A', b: 0, __v: 0 }

// Output 2: When statement #1 is commented
// Updation passed
// Original document: { a: 'A', b: 1, _id: ..., __v: 0 }
// Update Query: SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate({ a: 'A', b: { '$gte': 1 } }, { '$set': { b: 0 } })
// Latest document : { _id: ..., a: 'A', b: 0, __v: 0 }


Did you change your incorrect answer to use $inc after reading my answer?

@jQueeny, yes I had read yours, recalled $inc and then added $inc into this post. The previous code "await ...One({ a: 'A' }, { { b: 0 } })" was intentional. I was thinking this way that - the 1st write causing the 2nd write to a conflict can be "anything". The thing is it must reduce the value in such a way that the latter write should conflict with the former. That is the reason for setting this { b : 0 }. I reviewed it because most of the readers would relate the 1st write with the 2nd write and would help them to read better if they are similar- although it is not necessary.

continuing with the previous comment: the 2nd write mentioned over there is the line "statement-2". Per se it does not use $inc, still the line "deducting value" does the same. The change in the post, made these two writes similar for better reading. @jQueeny, You are most welcome to spot any issues with it, as we all know, the whole objective of these initiatives is to create "useful content for everyone" and it needs to have a collaborative effort.

First of all, I recommend setting a rate limit on your endpoint, such as 1 request per second.
Second, if you haven't already defined a check on balance column to prevent negative balances, you should do so.
(While I'm not an expert on MongoDB), you can achieve this by using a serializable transaction. This would involve selecting and updating the user's balance, inserting a new record into the withdrawal table, and then committing the transaction. If the check fails, the transaction would be rolled back.
For financial applications, stored procedures can be a good approach.
Here's an example:
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

select "balance", "recordID" into "_balance", "_recordID" 
from "Balance"
where "userID" = "in_userID"
for update;

if ("_balance"< "in_amount") raise exception('INSUFFICENT_BALANCE'); end if;

update "Balance" set "balance" = "balance" - "in_amount" where "recordID" = "_recordID";

insert into "Withdrawal" () values ();

COMMIT;


Mongoose v5 schemas support the min and max schema validatiors so you can apply a min of 0 to balance so that it's impossible to go below it like so:
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    balance: { 
        type: Number, 
        min: 0
    }
})

You can use $inc to increment the balance field by a negative amount but I would first check that req.body.amount is a positive integer. Then when you do the update make sure you use findByIdAndUpdate or findOneAndUpdate with { runValidators: true } option like so:
// convert string to integer
const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);

// now only do update if positive integer
if(Math.sign(amount) > 0){
   const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
   {
      $inc: {
         balance: -amount
      }
   },{ runValidators: true, new: true });
}else{
  //Return a response that amount must be positive amount
}

